# How to extract license information from AutoCAD?

Tags: license, license-key, autocad

I currently have a licensed copy of AutoCAD LT 2008 on my machine, but in a recent clearout the product CD (with the serial number on it) was thrown out.

What is the best way to recover this serial?

A free offical path is obviously preferred if it exists

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ABOUT` command in Autocad to bring up the about window which should show your serial. Alternatively try one of [many key finder programs](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/productkeysactivation/tp/topkeyfinder.htm) which will pull it from the registry.

Normally it is also baked into the registry as a string value called `SerialNumber` under:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\$ReleaseNumber\$BuildNumber
```

Replace variables accordingly.

Comment: Thanks John, under about/product serial number it says 000-00000000. Not sure why this is; though i did have to request a confirmation code from Autodesk when i installed. I also tried looking through the registry - no "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Autodesk\AutoCAD\..." path

Comment: Did you try the keyfinders?...

Comment: Regarding that 000-00000000 serial, this might be related, although it is not a solution to your question: http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/ps/dl/item?linkID=9240617&id=7294572&siteID=123112

Comment: hmmm bummer, tried magic jellybean its just coming up with the 000-00(..) serial, thanks guys. Upvoted John T because his answer probably solves this Q for most people